# AWS SNS push to an android mobile from Ec2 standalone java app

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I have a standalone java application that runs on my EC2 instance. 
I want to send a push message to a registered mobile.

I have registered on Firebase and configured server key etc on AWS SNS console. My server application then uses AWS SDK to push the message to client.

Now when trying to push , I am getting the following exception:

```
.IllegalArgumentException: Request endpoint must have a valid hostname, but it did not: https://sns.https%3A%2F%2Fsns.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com.amazonaws.com
        at com.amazonaws.auth.AWS4Signer.addHostHeader(AWS4Signer.java:548)
        at com.amazonaws.auth.AWS4Signer.sign(AWS4Signer.java:237)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1304)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
```

Comment: can you share how you're constructing the SNS client in your Java server app?